# Wget doesn't download recursively after following a redirect

Tags: linux, redirect, wget

Here is the way I use wget:

```
wget --recursive --level=10 --convert-links btlregion.ru
```

This [page](http://btlregion.ru/) redirects to [this](http://www.btlregion.ru/). When I run `wget` like above, it follows the redirect, but then only downloads that page - not all pages recursively.

I've already tried `--max-redirects=1` and `--domains=www.btlregion.ru` and it doesn't work.

If I invoke `wget` directly on [this page](http://www.btlregion.ru/), the recursive download works.

Comment: Can you tell us what site you're really using?

Comment: What would you want it to do? Give a fully qualified url if you want to download from a specific sub-domain. Example.com has probably only one subdomain, www.example.com

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I get the same behavior for all websites that redirect to their www subdomain.

Comment: @PMF, There is max_redirects option so I think that wget just should follow redirects. Unfortunately it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: What are you _expecting_ to get? The actual redirect http response?

Comment: @PMF, I just expect wget to follow redirects and download those pages. When I access the http://example.com it redirects me to http://www.example.com and all links there look like http://www.example.com/something so I guess this is why I get just one page. Wget just doesn't follow these links

Comment: Without knowing the site, it will be hard to help. We'd need to know exactly which headers it sends.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't quite follow. For me, the above command exactly does what he's supposed to: It effectively downloads index.html from example.com. Since that's the only page on this host, there's nothing else to do.

Comment: @sleske, Ok, here is one site for example: http://btlregion.ru

Comment: @PMF, this command should download the whole site I guess, not just one specific page.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm this: Wget does not download recursively if it has to follow a redirect first. I'll look into this...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `--span-hosts` (`-H`) with `--domains`:

```
wget --recursive --level=10 --convert-links -H \
--domains=www.btlregion.ru btlregion.ru
```

`--span-hosts` allows `wget` to follow links pointing to other domains, and `--domains` restricts this to only follow links to the listed domains, to avoid downloading the internet.

The option `--domains` will, somewhat contrary to intuition, *only* work together with `-H`. This is mentioned in the docs, but in a way that's hard to understand.

Comment: There's one problem I've found just now. When I use `--span-hosts` wget also requests external urls.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: You can use `--domains` to restrict the effect of `--span-hosts`. I edited my answer.

Comment: I use `--domains=domain.com,www.domain.com` but in my case it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: Sorry, no idea. Maybe ask a new question. Ideally on superuser.com, it's more suitable there. You can link this question.